# How to access USB camera through Qt c++ gui application

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am new to Qt GUI development. I have installed Qt GUI on windows platform. I need to setup a Qt C++ based GUI application to run connected USB camera. I tried to find out the related example but mostly based on webcam application. Is there any suggested example for accessing USB camera via Qt C++ GUI, I can go through?

Answer (score 1):

There is no essential difference between "webcam" and "usb camera". A webcam is a video camera that feeds or streams an image or video in real time. This means that your USB camera can be a webcam if it supports such a function.

To accomplish your task, use the qt documentation and it's perfect examples, like this [camera example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-camera-example.html).

Also, could be useful:

1. [Recording Video from USB Cam with Qt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650710/recording-video-from-usb-cam-with-qt5)
2. [Camera Overview](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cameraoverview.html)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt suggestion ans sharing the link. I have checked the'camera example' and tested it with Qt creator, It works well but since I use Qt on visual studio as VS tools and cross compile it through visualGDB to deploy it on my embedded board (linux), it doesn't.
Sorry, I am new to it. Are there many configuration I need to set up before cross compiling it?  Please suggest~

Comment: @Emlinux i don't have any problems with cross compiling. I guess there is something wrong with your environment. I recommend you to create another Question at this site.